# Saving HTTP requests from Chrome's DevTools

Tags: google-contacts-api

I'm currently working on my Bachelor's Degree paper and I want to create an environment for software testing.

I found that the requests shown in the Network tab of Chrome's Developer tools would be very helpful for what I'm trying to develop.

So I was wondering...Is there a way of saving these kind of requests in a file on my local or to access them through Java code?

Answer (score 1):

Is your goal to save the request or response data?

If you're interested in saving the responses, you could either save the entire page, or save individual requests using the network requests tab in the Chrome Inspector.

[image: Network Tab]

Comment: I would like to save both the requests and the responses,something like a log that preserves all my activity on that page.

Comment: You can record both and save them as sessions, but I have a feeling your particular scenario would be best solved by using a local proxy & recording tool, rather than trying to manage it all through developer tools. 

Depending on your platform you can use Fiddler2 (Win), or something like Charles proxy (Mac). Both are proxies, but come with a nice GUI which will also allow you to record, intercept and modify the response on the fly

Comment: I'll also try that,it sounds like a better fit for what I'm trying to achieve.Thank you! :)

Comment: Too bad that this "save as" button doesn't appear for all network requests.